# Match partial string in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in a VB macro where in the AUT Excel contains 5 sheets. In 3rd sheet I have 6 columns

In the 5th sheet. I have 3 Input boxes and 3 output boxes.
If user enters partial string from column 1 , column 2 and column 3 in inputbox1 , inputbox2 and inputbox 3, corresponding results should get displayed in outputbox1, outputbox2, outputbox3

But the code doesn't work if the input string is comparing with the data which has more values. So its like kind of hard coding this values in the if condition which is not feasible.

```
    `text3 Like "*NB" Or text3 Like 
    "*NS" Or text3 Like "*NF" Or text3 Like "*PE")`
```

I got this code snippet from the answers which is not displaying the results

```
`If (text1 Like ("*" & text4 & "*") And text2 Like ("*" & text5 & "*") And text3 Like ("*" & text6 & "*")) Then`
```

Please letme know if anything i need to add in the IF condition to match the partial string

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific (you even didn't ask a question) and needs to include your code because Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please read [ask] then [edit] your question and add the code you already have tried and ask a *specific* question to it. Also [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) might help you to ask a good question.

Comment: Edited the question. Kindly check @Peh

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I am not getting any error in compilation.But if user enters partial string, the code can't match it with the original string.For e.g. In column a value is "Additional Insured, Leased Premises" . If user inputs "Additional" only. it should match and display the corresponding result

Comment: I am not getting any error on compilation. Above code is not able to match the partial user input data , say "Additional" , with the column A data "Additional Insured, Leased Premises" .

Comment: You should use `InStr` instead of `=`... `InStr(Longstring, findThisString)` will return 0 for no match, and the starting position if the sub string is found. So `If Instr("my string", "string") > 0` returns true

Comment: I have tried with InStr , the issue with is that , if any other column contains the data which user has provided wrongly, it displays the results of that row.Lets say column 1 = "FAB5", column 2 = "5", column 3 = "NS, NF".Now if user mistakenly provides value as  "1" for column 1 , value for column 2 = "5" and column 3 = "NS", it displaying the result of some nth column which contains column 1 = "DFR1"

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need `Like` operator....

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator

Comment: I have checked with Like .But not sure .its not working

Comment: but if you use like operator you can find more than one match record - excel in you code display last

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Find` and `FindNext` instead. This will find the first instance that matches `input1` and then test if `input2` and `input3` are also satisfied. If so it sets the values that you wanted. If not it finds the next possible match.

```
Set Sheet1 = Worksheets(1)

Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
With Sheet1.Columns(1)
    Set c = .Find(input1, lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            If sheet3.Cells(c.Row, 2).Value2 = input2 And sheet3.Cells(c.Row, 3).Value2 = input3 Then
                Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value2 = Sheet1.Cells(c.Row, 5).Value2
                Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value2 = sheet2.Cells(c.Row, 6).Value2
                Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value2 = sheet3.Cells(c.Row, 4).Value2
                Exit Do
            Else
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            End If
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I am getting an Object Required Error @Tom

Comment: @newuser Can you try it again now

Comment: Hi. Code is running fine now but the output is not getting displayed correctly. Please letme know if i stick to my original code then instead of Like can i use any other operator to match the part string

Comment: What's happening with the output for it 'not getting displayed correctly' You could try using `Instr` function instead

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried as below

```
If (input1 Like ("*" & output4 & "*") And input2 Like ("*" & output5 & "*") And input3 Like ("*" & output6 & "*"))
```

Comment: Hi all.I will check in a while and let you know

Comment: Hi @Karthick Gunasekaran , I have checked the above code which you have provided.But its showing no results. I have edited my question with the output and the codes so that you can check